# Interfacing a 5v 16x2 JHD 162A LCD to Tiva C series TM4C123 microcontroller (3.3v)

Tags: microcontroller, lcd, launchpad

I'm trying to interface JHD 162A LCD display to a tiva c launchpad tm4c123 using Keil.

1. trying to read the busy flag, when i switch the port as input port, it becomes 0x80 means D7= 1 (busy), what should i do as it is not changing back to zero?
2. Should I use voltage converter to convert 3.3v to 5v?
3. I'm giving external 5v to lcd, should it be given using launchpad?

Comment: Can you give more details on the issue?

Comment: I think there is voltage incompatibility, I tried using opto-coupler, buffers but nothing seemed to work!